# History of triangulation

Tags: discoveries, resource-recommendation, geography

[Snell](https://www.britannica.com/science/geoid/The-introduction-of-triangulation) tends to be quoted as the person to develop triangulation in geodesy. I don't believe, however, that triangulation was invented only then. For example, [here](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Al-Biruni/) Al-Biruni is mentioned to have "introduced techniques to measure the earth and distances on it using triangulation".

It will be challenging to identify *the* person responsible for the invention of triangulation, so I'm looking for a timeline/reliable sources that would give me a better idea of the full story.

Comment: [Wikipedia's history section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation_(surveying)#History) gives the timeline with reference to [Hill's History of Engineering in Classical and Medieval Times](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_History_of_Engineering_in_Classical_an/MqSXc5sGZJUC?hl=en):"In the field, triangulation methods were apparently not used by the Roman specialist land surveyors, the agrimensores; but were introduced into medieval Spain through Arabic treatises on the astrolabe, such as that by Ibn al-Saffar (d. 1035). Abu Rayhan Biruni (d. 1048) also introduced triangulation..."